# How to download an TreeView from server

Tags: ios, objective-c

From my server I have a table like this,

```
objectId    parentId    id    locationName
```

I am trying to make a treeview under iOS using RATreeView. Every single object(cell) will have its unique id, and every cell that under some other cell will have its parentId which equals to its father's Id. Right now I'm trying to get those data from my server and assemble them as a treeview during runtime. But I really do not have a good algorithm to solve this. 
My algorithm is that get all the parentId in an array and id in another array, then find if there is anything equal in two arrays. But this comes with an problem, when there are more than two children under one cell, there will be duplicate parent cell. Anyone has any good idea?

Comment: So, 1 object has 1 or many parent?, and your unique id is `id` or `objectId`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better if you can get the response like this

`objectId, [childrendObjectId] (array of children id) id locationName`

You will do it easier.

But if you can't change the response, whenever you want to get the children of the `object`, just filter it.

I have a simple example here, hope it help

```
class MyObject {
    var id = 1 // I don't know id or objectId is uniqueId, so I remove your objectId, just edit it
    var parentId: Int?
    var locationName: String?

    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
    }
}

var array = [MyObject]()
for idx in 1...100 {
    let myObj = MyObject(id: idx)
    if idx > 10 {
        myObj.parentId = Int(arc4random() % 10 + 1)
    }
    array.append(myObj)
}

func childrenOf(_ object: MyObject) -> [MyObject] {
    return array.filter({$0.parentId == object.id})
}

let firstObject = array[0]
print(childrenOf(firstObject).map({$0.id}))
```